# How to get phone number, gender, and birthday with Cognito User Pool Federated to Google

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-api, amazon-cognito, google-people-api

I created a Cognito User Pool and enabled Google Identity Provider.

I added the Google app ID, App secret, and Authorize scope. But I am not sure if the authorize scope is correct, I just saw it here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

I set the authorize scope as `email openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read`

I already mapped the cognito user pool attributes to google attributes. But these three (3) attributes seems cannot get the value from google. phone number, birthday, gender. I am not really sure why.

[image]

Upon clicking the `continue with google`, I received an error on the callback that says that those fields are required. `https://www.example.com/?error_description=attributes+required%3A+%5Bgender%2C+birthdate%2C+phone_number%5D&error=invalid_request`

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem.
I think when integration user log in cognito, we can bind only attributes in integration user attribute from id token.

In this case, attributes that occur error does not exist in id token payload from google account.

I don't know my opinion is correct.
I hope this helps. :)